# How to copy backup files to remote share in SQL Server Agent job without AD/domain accounts involvement?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, maintenance

MS SQL Server 2012... with nightly databases backups to the same/local as SQL Server machine...

I am trying to add another SQL Server Agent Job to copy the  *.bak* files to remote (non-windows, i.e. Linux) share with non-Windows (non-AD) user/password credentials. 
I do not have any access to configuring or changing that access which is under control of other, quite remote people.

For this (copying) I created local user with the same user name and password, gave it permissions to the (source or local) backup-folders upon which all perfecly works from command line (`Win + К` or `cmd`) if to enter the command manually:

```
RUNAS /user:UserName /savecred "robocopy d:\SQLBACKUP  \\10.195.xx.yyy\backup /S /purge /MAXAGE:7 /MT:1 /Z"
```

but fails to run as **SQL Server Agent** job (type of step is "`Operating System(CmdExec)`". SQL Service Agent (with standard configuration of running under `[NT Service/SQLServiceAgent]` account, the job is owned by `SA` SQL Server superuser).

Can anybody explain me why it is failing and how to correctly make it running (taking into account that I do not have access to domain users configuration)?

Comment: Have you considered running the backup using a command line program and a scheduled task or PowerShell job instead of SQL Server Agent?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes, I eventually was forced to run it through Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler but it is unfortunate since: 1)it is decentralized; while logically and physically it depends on completion of (source for copy target) local backup through maintenance plans by SQLServerAgent job; 2)difficult to see how long it took or why they failed - the info is buried among thousands of (note it is on heavily used app server) app events (in `eventvwr.msc`; the copying takes hours);

Comment: 3)the last but not least - I'd like to understand why SQLServerAgent job fails and how to correctly succed with it.  It either starts and fails with no specific info in 3-4 min or hangs indefinitely without any errors and really not starting any copying

Comment: You know that you can run the backup that way too, not just the copy, so you don't have this dependency on some maintenance plan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question of why it is failing is that the service account on your server does not have the correct permissions to access the share.

I have an environment where I have 2 servers not on a domain.  Using `SQL Server Agent` proxies is the way I solved this.

I have a special account I use for the 2 machines (Your accounts with the same name and password) which I had to add to the instance level credentials (under security in SSMS Object explorer) (see MSDN article ["Create a Credential"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190703.aspx) )  and [add an agent proxy under the Operating System (CmdExec)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) .

Once those are created you can select the account to run as (the name you gave your proxy) and it will work.  However this is on 2008 and I have not played with the 2012 agent that much.
Should still work the same though.

You would then use your robocopy line "robocopy d:\SQLBACKUP  \10.195.xx.yyy\backup /S /purge /MAXAGE:7 /MT:1 /Z" as your command (I use xcopy but it works the same).

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Ill use this style in my future postings.

Comment: I just wanted to insert the space between source and destination directory in copy-pasted from my answer `robocopy` command (which originally was with an error) but the edit with less than 6 symbols changed was not accepted. So, I had to expand my editing...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to copy files to the networked computer is to use source computer domain credentials - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128282/51798