# Once more about SQL Server virtual accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, network

Let me reboot [my question on SQL Server virtual accounts permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51470/is-it-viable-to-attribute-permissions-to-sql-server-virtual-accounts-nt-service)

The (same) MSDN article on the same version 2012 of SQL Server "[Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)" states in "[File System Permissions Related to Unusual Disk Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Unusual_Locations)" section:

> "**Virtual accounts cannot be authenticated to a remote location**. All virtual accounts use the permission of machine account. Provision the machine account in the format `<domain_name>\<computer_name>$`."

If "virtual accounts cannot be authenticated to a remote location" then why:

- to use permissions of of a machine account and
- in the the format of domain account?

The same article, in ["New Account Types Available with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#New_Accounts) section contains:

> " **Virtual Accounts**
>
> Virtual accounts in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are managed local accounts that provide the following features to simplify service administration. **The virtual account** is auto-managed, and **the virtual account can access the network in a domain environment**. If the default value is used for the service accounts during SQL Server setup on Windows `Server 2008 R2` or `Windows 7`, a virtual account using the instance name as the service name is used, in the format `NT SERVICE\<SERVICENAME>`. Services that run as virtual accounts access network resources by using the credentials of the computer account in the format `<domain_name>\<computer_name>$`"

How should I better understand accessing the network without authentication ?

Comment: I think there is answer for your question - http://serverfault.com/a/135874