# Why would you use a managed service account rather than a virtual account in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows, password, kerberos

In SQL Server 2012, service accounts are created as [virtual accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#New_Accounts) (VAs), as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Default_Accts), as opposed to [managed service accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#New_Accounts) (MSAs).

The important differences I can see for these, based on the descriptions:

- MSAs are domain accounts, VAs are local accounts
- MSAs use automagic password management handled by AD, VAs have no passwords
- in a Kerberos context, MSAs register SPNs automatically, VAs do not

Are there any other differences?  If Kerberos is not in use, why would a DBA ever prefer an MSA?

**UPDATE**: [Another user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51643/once-more-about-sql-server-virtual-accounts) has noted a [possible contradiction in the MS docs concerning VAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> The virtual account is auto-managed, and the virtual account can access the network 
>   in a domain environment.

versus

> Virtual accounts cannot be authenticated to a remote location. All virtual accounts 
>   use the permission of machine account. Provision the machine account in the format
>   `<domain_name>\<computer_name>$`.

What is the "machine account"?  How/when/why does it get "provisioned"?  What is the difference between "accessing the network in a domain environment" and "authenticating to a remote location [in a domain environment]"?

Comment: Your last paragraph added 4 more questions.  S/O rules recommend one question per request.  I can answer one of these questions:  A "Machine account" is a local (NT) service account.  Each machine has one.  When you run a NT service as "System", it runs under this special local account.  Since it is not managed by a domain, it can't really (inherently) be trusted by other machines in a domain.  The account is automatically created when the OS is installed.  It is a throw-back to the days of peer-to-peer networks.

Comment: So if "all virtual accounts use the permission of the machine account" then by this definition, it couldn't possibly "access the network in a domain environment".

Comment: (in my previous message, I left-out something).  When a server joins a domain, the local "System" account gets mapped to a domain account <domain_name>\<computer_name>$.  That account is an actual domain account.

Comment: I would say, it is not typical to use a machine account to "access the network in a domain environment". As you can imagine, it is pretty generic and therefore presents a generous back-door.  You could grant permissions for that account, just like any other account, but it is discouraged.

Comment: It can't be all that atypical.  VAs, which "use the permission of the machine account", are the default account type for almost all the MSSQL12 service accounts.  Either MS left out a sentence like "however, it is not recommended to use VAs to access the network in a domain" or this is precisely what is intended.  That is why I asked the question.

Comment: Good point!  Since this is the default (simplest) way of doing things, it probably looks like the correct way of doing it, to most people.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way I see it.

When you use a VA, you impersonate the machine account.

The problem is, that it is easy to make a VA or use an existing one (ex. NT Authority\NETWORKSERVICE). If you grant the machine account access to an instance, an application that is running as a VA will be able to connect to that instance and perform actions.

With a managed account, you will have to provide the credentials for that account to whatever application wants to use them, allowing you more granularity with permissions.