# How to make SQL Server Agent job history less verbose?

Tags: sql-server, logs, maintenance, debugging

So, I've created a SQL Server Agent job, according to the [answer to my prev question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51466/how-to-copy-backup-files-to-remote-share-in-sql-server-agent-job-without-ad-doma):

[image: General]

[image: Advanced]

[image]

running nightly (at 2:11) according to the schedule:

[image: Nightly Schedule]

There are 9 .bak files in 3 subdirectory of d:\backup\ source folder, 3 old bakup files are being deleted and 3 new is being created by another preceding SQL Server Agent job.

The described here job copy-purges files but... what the heck the history of this `Copy&Purge BAKs` SQL ServerAgent job  shows 96 items:

[image]

How to make it less verbose?

Eventvwr.msc doesn't contain any eroors for the corresponding period of time (of job run).

**UPDATE:**

So, I've made these changes

[image]

and it seems it simply truncates a per-job log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you just wanted to reduce the number of rows shows up there or actually want SQL server Agent not to log that much of data. but if it is to limit the number of rows to log per job and/or total in job history then you can set those from SSMS as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changed "per job" to 20 (from 100) Shall see the results tomorrow, I hope it will be proportional and not just truncate after 20% of job processing

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to uncheck this:

[image]

The job step properties screen allows you to prevent the output from the job being recorded in the job history.

Comment: I really need this output especially for new or fresh modified jobs...as well as for old ones

Comment: Unchecking this option will only impact the job that you do it on. So you need to either do that or add the /np option from the answer above to limit the amount of output from robocopy.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the job step history is recording all of the output from the robocopy command. How about adding suppression arguments to the command line? From [the Robocopy topic on TechNet](https://web.archive.org/web/20170904042840/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx):

```
/ns  -- Specifies that file sizes are not to be logged.
/nc  -- Specifies that file classes are not to be logged.
/nfl -- Specifies that file names are not to be logged.
/ndl -- Specifies that directory names are not to be logged.
/np  -- Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number 
        of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.
```

See also: the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: I do not see that "file sizes", "file names", "dir names" or "the number of filesor directories copied so far" are being logged. Just to note that other SQL Server Agent jobs (that execute maintenance plans) have no more than a single record per SQL Server Agent job step

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск well, I can't really tell from your screen shot what is or isn't being logged. I was merely showing you all of the ways you can suppress output.